# Persistent prompt in Linux (not just shell)

Tags: linux, command-prompt, prompt, tty

I spent several decades using Digital Equipment Corporation's VMS operating system, and one of the things I really miss is the terminal driver's 'read-with-prompt' functionality.

It would display the prompt and position the cursor for input, as you'd expect, but the prompt was **immune** to things like CTRL/U, CTRL/R, and CTRL/W.  It was an attribute of the read operation, and every time the terminal driver was ready to read from the terminal with this option, it would show the prompt.  The user couldn't erase it, so if it went off the screen he'd still know what was being requested.

This is one of the few things that I think VMS did better than U*X -- unless there's a Linuxish way of doing this.

So far I've never found it, but maybe I'm just not looking in the right place.

*Is* there a way on Linux to read from a tty with a persistent prompt?

Thanks!

Comment: No, not as far as I know. Unix deliberately keeps the terminal driver simple, it doesn't know anything about prompting.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I personally disagree with it being off-topic because it has to do with programming for interactive input from the user.  However, noted, and I'll try Super User.  Thanks.